# Ensure capacity of List

Tags: java, list

I was browsing about how to create own list and landed on this site http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaDatastructureList/article.html where they had the below method.

```
private void ensureCapa() {
    int newSize = elements.length * 2;
    elements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, newSize);
}
```

I found similar methods in many other sites and understood what ensureCapacity does. But I don't understand why the length is multiplied by 2 (elements.length * 2). Is there a specific reason or does it vary with data type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is made to make `add()` operation average cost `O(1)`: `1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^n = 2 * 2^n - 1` -> n insertions cost ~O(n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doubling the capacity of a list when it's full is done for a couple of reasons.

As @jheimbouch and @user3437460 stated, it just kinda makes sense intuitively. You'd want to increase it in some proportional amount to the current size of the list. Adding a few fixed elements at the end each time could end up being really bad for a big fat list.

It's more efficent in general. If you don't have a good idea of what size your list is going to be (as when designing your own array-based list class for general use), if you double the size of the list each time, then on average over each large set of insertions, each insert will take `O(1)` constant time (this is called an Amortized Constant Time operation).

Think about it, the cost of resizing an array is `n`. So the only thing we can adjust is how often we do that. The more often we do it, the more tightly bound our array is to our actual data size, so we use up less memory. The less often we do it, we save on CPU cycles.

There's proofs abound regarding the time complexity, but here's one I found quickly http://anh.cs.luc.edu/363/notes/06A_Amortizing.html

Long story short, it's mathematically sound in the general case, and strikes a very good balance between memory consumption and processing time.

Answer (score 1):

It is a common practice so as to not have to copy the Arrays all the time.
For example, if it was `elements.length + 1`, you would be copying to a new array every time an element got added.

So in short, it's arbitrary, you could increase the size by whatever you choose.

Comment: Particularly, by increasing the size of the list by a factor, `c >= 2`, you can achieve amortized constant insertion time. So it's not entirely arbitrary.

Comment: @CollinD, do you have a source on that?

Comment: There's about a billion different proofs of this, my particular source is a class a few years ago in college, but here's one I found pretty quickly http://anh.cs.luc.edu/363/notes/06A_Amortizing.html Basically the point is on average, you end up with O(1) insertion time, because the first `n` insertions take O(1), and then one takes `2n e O(n)` time. Rinse and repeat, on average it's `2n/n = 2 e O(1)` for insertions.

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't understand why the length is multiplied by 2 (elements.length * 2). Is there a specific reason or does it vary with data type?

You won't want to increase the size by a fixed value say 5. By doubling the capacity based on your current number of elements to certain extend ensures efficiency (so that you won't have to perform an array copy all the time).

Imagine you have 1000 elements and it is full now, it is logical to double it since it is possible to have another 1000 elements coming in. But if you add the capacity with a fixed value, you are likely to add too much capacity or too little.

When you add too much, you are wasting memory, but if you add to little, you are likely needed to perform another copying of array too frequently which isn't efficient because that means you are more likely to adjust the current array when you add new elements.